# Ng-show not showing product's detail

Tags: angularjs

I'm making an exercise about the AngularJS, and i created a table that will load the data from database, i have a "Detail" button, when i click on that button, it will assign a new row below the row which contain a button i clicked. It's work fine but the problem is when i click the "Detail" button, it the detail of all, i just want it to show the detail of which product i clicked.

Here is my HTML code:

```js
var app = angular.module("dataApp", []);
app.controller("dataExcuteController", function ($scope, $window,$http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/sachonline/public/administrator/theloai/dstheloai').then(function (response) {
        $scope.theloai = response.data.message.ds_theloai;
        $scope.isLoading = false;
    });
    
    $scope.detailtheloai = function (item) {
        $scope.showdetail = true;
    };

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="dataApp" ng-controller="dataExcuteController">
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="text-center">
        <th>STT</th>
        <th>Tên thể loại</th>
        <th>Trạng thái</th>
        <th>
            <span><i class="fa fa-cog text-muted"></i></span>
        </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="item in theloai">
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">@{{ item.tl_ma }}</td>
            <td>@{{ item.tl_ten }}</td>
            <td class="text-center" ng-if="item.tl_trangThai==1">
                <span><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i></span>
            </td>

            <td class="text-center" ng-if="item.tl_trangThai==0">
                <span><i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger"></i></span>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning text-white mr-3 pt-0 pl-2 pr-2" ng-click="detailtheloai(item)"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success text-white mr-3 pt-0 pl-2 pr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editForm" ng-click="edittheloai($index)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger text-white pt-0 pl-2 pr-2" ng-click="removetheloai($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="showdetail">
            <td colspan="4">
                <table class="table table-info table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-right">Mã thể loại:</th>
                            <td>@{{ item.tl_ma }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-right">Tên thể loại:</th>
                            <td>@{{ item.tl_ten }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-right">Trạng thái:</th>
                            <td class="text-center" ng-if="item.tl_trangThai==1">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i></span>
                            </td>

                            <td class="text-center" ng-if="item.tl_trangThai==0">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-times-circle text-danger"></i></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="{!!asset('js/showlist.js')!!}"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You're using a boolean. A boolean can't tell you which product was clicked. Instead, you need a variable that stores... the item itself. Then you'll test if the current item in the loop is the clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the show value for every item, therefore I propose you this changes:

js:

```
 $scope.detailtheloai = function (item) {
    item.showdetail = true;
};
```

html:

```
<tr ng-show="item.showdetail">
```